# Animate drawing LineRenderer with many position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `LineRenderer` with many positions and am try to animate the line from point a -> b, b ->c, etc...

First, I save all the positions of the line, then I reset the `positionCount` so that it is not visible at the start. But when I draw the `lineRenderer` in a loop, increasing `positionCount` over each iteration, and when drawing the next line starts, the previous line shakes a little and the width changes momentarily.

Here is code:

```
public float LineDrawSpeed;

void Start()
{
  lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
  int lineCountInLineRenderer = lineRenderer.positionCount - 1;
  var startPositions = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount];
  lineRenderer.GetPositions(startPositions);
  lineRenderer.positionCount = 1;
  StartCoroutine(LineDrawCoroutine(startPositions));
}
```

Here is coroutine:

```
IEnumerator LineDrawCoroutine(Vector3[] positions)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < positions.Length - 1; i++)
  {
    if (lineRenderer.positionCount <= i + 1)
    lineRenderer.positionCount++;

    lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, positions[i]);
    float timePass = 0f;
    while (timePass < LineDrawSpeed)
    {
      var factor = timePass / LineDrawSpeed;
      factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, factor);

      lineRenderer.SetPosition(i + 1, Vector3.Lerp(positions[i], positions[i + 1], factor));

      timePass += Mathf.Min(Time.deltaTime, LineDrawSpeed - timePass);
      yield return null;
    }
  }
}
```

The mechanic works well, but something is wrong with animation.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Is your main question: How do I get this to animate without any shaking or width changes?

Comment: @whathm Yes, exactly. How to animate LR with many position and without strange visual changing of lines.

Comment: Are you trying to do a curved line or straight line?

Comment: @whathm, straight line.

Comment: Got it. I added a solution below. Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Thanks, I will check it later. I see the code. Am I right that I can nullify the all LR points, and then set them a value from a previously saved array of the points LR in loop? Without changing the positionCount. I text here when I use your variant of code.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then yeah. That's basically what my code does, so I think you should be good. I set the positionCount in the beginning and then just set the Vectors within it rather than increasing the actual positionCount value.

Answer (score 2):

I found this width variation topic quite interesting.
As far as I checked, there two important points to take into account.

1.- LineRenderer render billboard lines.

https://docs.huihoo.com/unity/5.3/Documentation/en/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html

Billboards are 2D elements incrusted in a 3D world, whose orientation is automatically computed so that it always faces the camera. This explains width variations along with camera movement.

2.- If the camera is not moving, take into account that: As defined in the documentation, width attribute defines:  "a width value and a curve value to control the width of your trail along its length.
The curve is sampled at each vertex, so its accuracy is limited by the number of vertices in your trail. The overall width of the trail is controlled by the width value."

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html

So as you are dinamically changing the vertexes of your line, the overall width of your trail might suffer changes.

So I think that your algorithim works fine, and that the width variations comes along with the line renderer component.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. So, maybe it possible to draw LineRenderer without changing position count. I'll look in this direction. I don't want to create separate LR on each A-B line. I want to do my draw lines animation in one LR.

Comment: I did not think of that. You may handle many LR with one script and loop through them. I they al have the same width you might solve of minmize the width issue...

Comment: You mean create on each simple line a separate LR?

Comment: yes, I mean for each section you create a game object with the LR, the you create a global controller object with a reference to each so that you can loop through them all according to your animation logic, and check with that if you have the width variation issue.... It was your idea though ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty confident your issue lies in the fact that you are adding to the position count 
over and over again. Not 100% sure though.

Regardless, below is working code for how to incrementally increase the length of the line. It's just an `IEnumerator`, but you can just call it in `StartCoroutine` and it should work

This will work for a straight line, but will take some adjustments for a curved line (but I think you could make it work if you wanted to).

To explain this a bit extra, instead of incrementing and increasing the `positionCount`, and then adding the vector, I simply set the positionCount to the desired amount of vectors and then incrementally fill each vector in with the desired position. When setting them all right off the bat, they default to `0,0,0`, so just be sure this doesn't cause any issues for you.

Below is the code I use:

```
//  Using IEnumerator to ensure that the line is drawn over a specific amount of time
private IEnumerator DrawLine()
{
    float renderTime = 2f;                                      // total time for full line render
    int renderSteps = 75;                                       // desired resolution of render (higher amt of steps creates smoother render)
    float timeBetweenSteps = renderTime / renderSteps;          // time between each render step

    //  Grab the LineRenderer component that is attached to the gameObject and defined in Inspector
    LineRenderer lineRenderer = yourGameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

    //  Declare the endpoint
    Vector3 endPoint = new Vector3(0, 5, 0);

    //  Take the end point and break into the amount of steps we need in order to create 
    //  fully rendered line
    //  Create an additiveVector for the forLoop that will step through the renderSteps
    //  >>  Start at zero becuase zero is the localOrigin
    Vector3 stepVector = endPoint / renderSteps;
    Vector3 additiveVector = Vector3.zero;

    //  Setting the line's position element count to the render resolution because we will
    //  have to step through 
    lineRenderer.positionCount = renderSteps;

    //  For Loop that steps through each position element in the Line
    for (int i = 0; i != lineRenderer.positionCount; i++)
    {
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, additiveVector);            // set the position element to the additiveVEctor
        additiveVector += stepVector;                           // add one step to the additiveVector
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenSteps);      // Wait the appropriate step time before repeating the loop
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions. I hope this helps!

Comment: It doesn't work correctly. Because I already set positionCount in inspector, and this it sets to renderSteps. By the way, it draws only one line and set 75 position for it :D Well, and issue with line width stays.

Comment: @Fletchet Take renderSteps out and put it in your main method. Then pass it into the Enumerator like you did in your original example. And yes, I know it does that. It's to preset the increments that the line should be animated by. As for the width, if my code causes a width problem still, then it is probably something you set in on the LineRenderer in the inspector because I can copy and paste this code into a new project and have no issues... Let me know if you're still having issues.

Comment: I use inner loop where I divide each next point by 75 and SetPosition this. Zeroing all points does not work as it should, beacuse point 0, 0, 0 is visible on the screen, but when I start coroutine I do at start SetPosition(0, myPos[0]), then in the loop when I do SetPosition(i, nextPos) then the following strange artifact related with zero points.